# SQL Server stored procedure Nullable parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

**Problem**:
When values are provided to the following script then executed using a setup in C# like below (or in SQL Server environment) the values do not update in the database.

Stored procedure:

```
-- Updates the Value of any type of PropertyValue
-- (Type meaining simple Value, UnitValue, or DropDown)
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_UpdatePropertyValue]
    @PropertyValueID int,
    @Value varchar(max) = NULL,
    @UnitValue float = NULL,
    @UnitOfMeasureID int = NULL,
    @DropDownOptionID int = NULL
AS
BEGIN   
    -- If the Property has a @Value, Update it.
    IF @Value IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[PropertyValue]
        SET
            Value = @Value
        WHERE
            [dbo].[PropertyValue].[ID] = @PropertyValueID
    END
    -- Else check if it has a @UnitValue & UnitOfMeasureID
    ELSE IF @UnitValue IS NOT NULL AND @UnitOfMeasureID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[UnitValue]
        SET
            UnitValue = @UnitValue,
            UnitOfMeasureID = @UnitOfMeasureID
        WHERE
            [dbo].[UnitValue].[PropertyValueID] = @PropertyValueID          
    END
    -- Else check if it has just a @UnitValue
    ELSE IF @UnitValue IS NOT NULL AND @UnitOfMeasureID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[UnitValue]
        SET
            UnitValue = @UnitValue
        WHERE
            [dbo].[UnitValue].[PropertyValueID] = @PropertyValueID  
    END
    -- Else check if it has a @DropDownSelection to update.
    ELSE IF @DropDownOptionID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[DropDownSelection]
        SET
            SelectedOptionID = @DropDownOptionID
        WHERE
            [dbo].[DropDownSelection].[PropertyValueID] = @PropertyValueID
    END
END
```

When I do an execution of this script, like below, it does not update any values.

Example execution:

```cs
String QueryString = "EXEC [dbo].[usp_UpdatePropertyValue] @PropertyValueID, @Value, @UnitValue, @UnitOfMeasureID, @DropDownOptionID";
SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(QueryString, this._DbConn);

Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PropertyValueID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Value", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitValue", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UnitOfMeasureID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));
Cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DropDownOptionID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int));

Cmd.Parameters["@PropertyValueID"].Value = Property.Value.ID; // 1
Cmd.Parameters["@Value"].IsNullable = true;
Cmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = DBNull.Value;
Cmd.Parameters["@UnitValue"].IsNullable = true;
Cmd.Parameters["@UnitValue"].Value = DBNull.Value;
Cmd.Parameters["@UnitOfMeasureID"].IsNullable = true;
Cmd.Parameters["@UnitOfMeasureID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
Cmd.Parameters["@DropDownOptionID"].IsNullable = true;
Cmd.Parameters["@DropDownOptionID"].Value = 2; // Current Value in DB: 3
```

**Details:**

After running an execute (via C# code or SQL Server environment) it does not update `dbo.DropDownSelection.SelectedOptionID`. I'm guessing that it might be because `dbo.DropDownSelection.SelectedOptionID` is non-nullable and the parameter I'm using to set it is nullable (despite that when setting it shouldn't ever be null). Upon execution the return value is 0. If I run one of the Updates outside of the procedure they work perfectly, hence my suspicion that it has to do with null-able types.

**Question(s):**

Could this be because the parameters to the stored procedure are nullable and the fields I'm setting aren't?

If not, what could it be?

Comment: If you change those Insert and Updates to Selects, do you return data for the supplied parameters?

Comment: Yes. I updated my question, added "If I run one of the Updates outside of the procedure they work perfectly, hence my suspicion that it has to do with null-able types."

Comment: 1) I clarified my question a bit. I'm not trying to do output parameter.
2) The stored-procedure says it executes and it returns 0, but the values never update. I'm not sure what you mean by "via sql block".

Comment: Does your SP executes if you exexut it via sql block? In your case, since you have hardcoded `Cmd.Parameters["@Value"].IsNullable = true;
Cmd.Parameters["@Value"].Value = DBNull.Value;`, you might as well just omit it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you're passing in Null for every argument except for PropertyValueID and DropDownOptionID, right?  I don't think any of your IF statements will fire if only these two values are not-null.  In short, I think you have a logic error.

Other than that, I would suggest two things...

First, instead of testing for NULL, use this kind syntax on your if statements (it's safer)...

```
    ELSE IF ISNULL(@UnitValue, 0) != 0 AND ISNULL(@UnitOfMeasureID, 0) = 0
```

Second, add a meaningful PRINT statement before each UPDATE.  That way, when you run the sproc in MSSQL, you can look at the messages and see how far it's actually getting.

Comment: Wow, I feel dumb. It should be `ELSE IF @DropDownOptionID IS NOT NULL` like the rest of them :/ Thank you.

Comment: How is using `ISNULL(...` safer than `... IS NULL`? It seems like your suggestion is *less* safe because, for one reason at least, now you have a magic value (zero) that is treated as equivalent to `NULL`. If you're going to use or allow null values, testing for `NULL` and only `NULL` is the safest thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can/should set your parameter to value to DBNull.Value;

```
if (variable == "")
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = DBNull.Value;
}
else
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = variable;
}
```

Or you can leave your server side set to null and not pass the param at all.